# my mails from postfix are going to spam

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, sendmail

i know this question has been already asked. but my problem is so wierd.
i have done everything needed to be done for avoiding spam, but my mails are still going to spam folder.
my mail-tester.com score is 10/10.
my allaboutspam.com test resuls is good too as you can see in the link below : 
[test result](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test-report/?key=730551F2A3ACDF3B2303B6796FB2C725)

but mails are still going to spam, i don't know what to do, i have done everything on the internet.

Comment: This depends entirely on why your email gets marked as spam by the recipient -- can you be more specific with this question?

Comment: There are mail-test services that you can send a mail to, and they answer with the spamassassin logs so you see what influences your rating.

Answer (score 1):

This is also depends your email gets marked as spam by the user. Could you verify the RDNS and other mail (TEXT,MX, DKIM and DMRC) records.

Comment: it's not marked as spam by the user, it's going spam for every user i send email to,
actually google gives me a tip ( on receiver email) on why this is marked as spam but it doesn't specify the reason and says all possible reasons.
but the problem is according to that tip everything is fine. and yes i have all this records